# What is the fastest way to perform a date query in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

We have a 6B row table that is giving us challenges when retrieving data.

Our query returns values instantly when doing a...

```
SELECT * WHERE Event_Code = 102225120
```

That type of instant result is exactly what we need. We now want to filter to receive values for just a particular year - but the moment we add...

```
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PERFORMED_DATE_TIME) = 2017
```

...the query takes over 10 minutes to begin returning any values.

[Another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552299/oracle-date-index-is-slow-query-is-300-times-faster-without-it) mentions that indexes don't necessarily help date queries when pulling many rows as opposed to an individual row. There are other approaches like using TRUNC, or BETWEEN, or specifying the datetime in YYYY-MM-DD format for doing comparisons.

Of note, we do not have the option to add indexes to the database as it is a vendor's database.

What is the way to add a date filtering query and enable Oracle to begin streaming the results back in the fastest way possible?

Comment: `we do not have the option to add indexes` - ask your DBA for creating an index. If DBA is not willing to help, then ask your boss. Tell them than you need the index because the query is very slow and it unnecessarily eats database resources making the whole system slower.

Comment: @krokodilko - the point is the database is *"is a vendor's database"*: it is a regrettably common scenario that unauthorised changes to the database schema will invalidate a vendor's support contract. That is, they *"do not have the option"* for licensing reasons.

Comment: Six billion records is a lot of records: is this table partitioned?

Answer (score 1):

> Another SO post mentions that indexes don't necessarily help date queries when pulling many rows as opposed to an individual row

That question is quite different from yours. Firstly, your statement above applies to any data type, not only dates. Also the word **many** is relative to the number of records in the table. If the optimizer decides that the query will return **many** of all records in your table, then it may decide that a full scan of the table is faster than using the index. In your situation, this translates to how many records are in 2017 out of all records in the table? This calculation gives you the cardinality of your query which then gives you an idea if an index will be faster or not.

Now, if you decide that an index will be faster, based on the above, the next step is to know how to build your index. In order for the optimizer to use the index, it must match the condition that you're using. You are not comparing dates in your query, you are only comparing the year part. So an index on the date column will not be used by this query. You need to create an index on the year part, so use the same condition to create the index.

> we do not have the option to add indexes to the database as it is a vendor's database.

If you cannot modify the database, there is no way to optimize your query. You need to talk to the vendor and get access to modify the database or ask them to add the index for you.

Comment: Then is the implication of what you are saying is that no type of date query is faster than any other type? For example, EXTRACT performs equally as performant as BETWEEN and as TRUNC and as any other variation out there?

Comment: No, I didn't say that. Where do you see me comparing different functions in my answer? Of course there is difference between them. But none of them will give you a good performance on a big table without an index. If you use them correctly, the difference between them will be negligible comparing to having or not having an appropriate index. However, creating an appropriate index is significantly different between them and that's what makes the difference. For example, an appropriate index for `BETWEEN` is really tricky, but for your year query it is easy.

Comment: Yes - my question meant to implicitly imply speed differences that are *significantly* faster rather than insignificant differences - (which is also in alignment with the original question's desire)

Comment: Can you post an execution plan (or preferably a SQL Monitor Report) for the two queries. Then you will have a better chance of getting a true diagnosis rather than guesses.

Answer (score 1):

A function can also cause slowness for the number of records involved. Not sure if Function Based Index can help you for this, but you can try.

Had you tried to add a year column in the table? If not, try to add a year column and update it using code below.

```
UPDATE table
   SET year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PERFORMED_DATE_TIME);
```

This will take time though.

But after this, you can run the query below.

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM table 
  WHERE Event_Code = 102225120 AND year = 2017;
```

Also, try considering Table Partitioned for this big data. For starters, see link below,

link: https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/partitioned-tables-and-indexes

Comment: Yes, of course a function needs some execution time, but with such a simple function to extract the year the performance difference is negligible. Extracting the year to a separate column still needs an index on the new column, otherwise the query performance will not be big enough to warrant breaking the table's normality. We only break the table's normality when there is a meaningful difference, usually involving much more complex calculation than extracting the year, or when there is big number of hits to the column.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous IMHO:

> but the moment we add... 
>       AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PERFORMED_DATE_TIME) = 2017
>   ...the query takes over 10 minutes to begin returning any values.

Do you mean that

```
SELECT * WHERE Event_Code = 102225120
```

is fast, but

```
SELECT * WHERE Event_Code = 102225120 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PERFORMED_DATE_TIME) = 2017
```

is slow???

For starters I'll agree with Mitch Wheat that you should try to use `PERFORMED_DATE_TIME` between Jan 1, 2017 and Dec 31, 2017 instead of Year(field) = 2017. Even if you'd have an index on the field, the latter would hardly be able to make use of it while the first method would benefit enormously.

I'm also hoping you want to be more specific than just 'give me all of 2017' because returning over 1B rows is NEVER going to be fast.

Next, if you can't make changes to the database, would you be able to maintain a 'shadow' in another database? This would require that you create a table with all date-values AND the PK of the original table in another database and query those to find the relevant PK values and then JOIN those back to your original table to find whatever you need. The biggest problem with this would be that you need to keep the shadow in sync with the original table. If you know the original table only changes overnight, you could merge the changes in the morning and query all day. If the application is 'real-time(ish)' then this probably won't work without some clever thinking... And yes, your initial load of 6B values will be rather heavy =)

Comment: *Even if you'd have an index on the field, the latter would hardly be able to make use of it while the first method would benefit enormously*, you're assuming an index already exists on the date field. If that's true and we cannot modify the index or add a new one, then you're statement is valid. Otherwise, creating an index on the year will make searching by year as fast as searching using `BETWEEN` with an index on the field. Also in most cases the time is important and you need to include it in the `BETWEEN` range which makes it harder to use if there are records in the last fraction second

Comment: @RacilHilan true, I forgot that in Oracle you can put an index on `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PERFORMED_DATE_TIME)` directly. Being used to MSSQL that would require adding a calculated field and indexing that one to _materialize_ it, something that probably will be considered even more intrusive than simply adding an index on `YEAR FROM PERFORMED_DATE_TIME`. I was mostly trying to point out that `WHERE f(x) = @value` usually does NOT benefit a lot from an index on `x` but that converting the query to `WHERE x = f(@value)` will.

Comment: Yes, `f(x)` does not use an index on `x` at all, so same as no index. By the way, it's true that in SQL Server, you have to create the index on a computed field, but if you don't mark the computed field with `PERSISTED`, then it won't be stored in the table. That's almost like Oracle and MySQL. The only problem with that is you need to avoid using the computed field in all your query to avoid getting a performance hit. So I agree with you that this is more intrusive than the Oracle and MySQL way.

Answer (score 0):

May this could be usefull (because you avoid functions (a cause for context switching) and if you have an index on your date field, it could be used) :

```
with 
dt as
(
select
        to_date('01/01/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as d1,    
        to_date('31/01/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as d2    
       from dual
),  
   dates as
(
select 
        dt.d1 + rownum -1 as d
from dt
connect by dt.d1 + rownum -1 <= dt.d2
)
select *
from your_table, dates
where  dates.d = PERFORMED_DATE_TIME
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the date literal to RHS:

```
AND PERFORMED_DATE_TIME >= date '2017-01-01' 
AND PERFORMED_DATE_TIME < date '2018-01-01'
```

But without an (undisclosed) appropriate index on `PERFORMED_DATE_TIME`, the query is unlikely to be any faster.

One option to create indexes in third party databases is to script in the index and then before any vendor upgrade run a script to remove any indexes you've added. If the index is important, ask the vendor to add it to their database design.

Comment: That is, actually, a BETWEEN, is it not?

Comment: it is, but I've recently started using the equivalent syntax after reading Aaron Bertrand's article (although that is for sql server)... Between is implicitly  inclusive, but the above syntax is explicit.

Comment: Right; one should *know* what BETWEEN does. Using syntax like in your example, it is obvious.

Comment: `DATE '2017-12-31'` is `2017-12-31T00:00:00` so this will exclude any values that are between `2017-12-31T00:00:01` and `2017-12-31T23:59:59`. You would be better using `AND PERFORMED_DATE_TIME >= DATE '2017-01-01' AND PERFORMED_DATE_TIME < DATE '2018-01-01'`.

Comment: Updated: I knew something was nagging me about the time portion! Thanks

Comment: @MT0 You're right that an explicit range is better with dates when the time portion is important. Not only you have to specify the time with `BETWEEN`, but it's also hard to get it right if there are records in the last fraction second (i.e. between 23:59:59 and 00:00:00).

Comment: Mitch, this applies to all database and even all programming languages. It's not about the syntax of `BETWEEN`, it's about the accuracy of date. If the time portion is not used (example birthdates), then `BETWEEN` can be safely used. Otherwise, using a range like you did is easier to get right and clearer.

Comment: @Racil : I know. It was an omission, not lack of knowledge.